# Unable to connect to Dapr (self-hosted) using gRPC client

Tags: docker-compose, dapr

I am working on an application that connects an app running using Dapr (self-hosted) and a gRPC client. I use the common.proto and runtime.proto. I am able to get the connection working when using the DAPR CLI.

But when using the DAPR self-hosted instance I am getting the following error when using the gRPC port:

```cs
Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="invoke API is not ready", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1621435606.713000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:54000","file":"..\..\..\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc","file_line":1068,"grpc_message":"invoke API is not ready","grpc_status":13}")'
```

and this when I am using the dapr http port

```
Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1621435606.713000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:54000","file":"..\..\..\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc","file_line":1068,"grpc_message":"invoke API is not ready","grpc_status":13}")'
```

Below is the compose file for DAPR server

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  daprserver:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}daprserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile        
    environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    networks:
    - daprserver-network
  daprserver-dapr:
    image: "daprio/dapr:latest"
    command: [ "./daprd", 
        "-app-id", "daprserver", 
        "-app-port", "80", 
        "-dapr-http-port","53001",
        "-dapr-grpc-port","53000"]
    ports:
    - 54000:53000 #grpc external:internal
    - 54001:53001 #http external:internal
    depends_on:
    - daprserver  
    networks:
    - daprserver-network
networks:
  daprserver-network:
```

and the client code is below:

```
 var channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1:54000", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
                var daprClient = new Dapr.Client.Autogen.Grpc.v1.Dapr.DaprClient(channel);
                var request = new InvokeServiceRequest
                {
                    Id = "daprserver",
                    Message = new InvokeRequest
                    {
                        Method = "weatherforecast",
                        HttpExtension = new HTTPExtension
                        {
                            Verb = HTTPExtension.Types.Verb.Get,
                        }
                    }
                };

                var invokeResponse = daprClient.InvokeServiceAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                var json = invokeResponse.Data.Value.ToStringUtf8();
```

Am I missing a setting or is there any issue with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the app using the below command in the command prompt from the project file. It will run both dapr and your application, you can see two processes in the task manager one is dapr.exe, and the second is dotnet.exe.

```
dapr run --app-id yourappid dotnet run
```